Spring Boot - JPADataSourcePool-121 - Exception during pool initialization
During the building of jenkins pipeline in the build step i face this error:
2024-11-25 11:55:52.901+0100 [@project.artifactId@] ERROR [main] [//] [c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException] - JPADataSourcePool-121 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.edb.util.PSQLException: Connection attempt failed.
    at com.edb.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:393)
    at com.edb.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at com.edb.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:226)
    at com.edb.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:483)
    at com.edb.Driver.connect(Driver.java:276)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at com.edb.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:234)
    at com.edb.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:97)
    at com.edb.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at com.edb.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:240)

Some information i see in the application.yml (values are defined in the pod container's env variables):
connectors:
  jpaConfigurations:
    connection:
      url: ${DSPOSTGRESQL_URL:}
      driver-class-name: com.edb.Driver
      username: ${DSPOSTGRESQL_USERNAME:}
      password: ${DSPOSTGRESQL_PASSWORD:}
      connectionPoolSize: ${DSPOSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE}
      timeout: 6000
      hibernateDialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      hbm2ddl: none
      show-sql: true

I've tried to build/run the application in local and it works fine, the only thing that has recently changed within the pom is the major version of 2 libraries i have to use due to my company policies.

Make sure the URL is correct and that you can access said server from your build server. This looks like a firewall/routing issue from your build server to your test db server.
